# jCarousel active class on items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcarousel

in this example http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html i need an active state on li so it should look like this whenever I slide.

Any idea anyone? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.jcarousel-control a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var txt = $(this).text();
   $('.jcarousel-list li').removeClass('active');
   $('.jcarousel-list li:eq(' + (txt - 1) + ')').addClass('active')
})
```

Comment: thanks! works only when u click navigation not prev next links, thanks tough!